# mysql rank by column value grouped by column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to figure out how to rank based on 2 different column numbers in laravel but raw mysql will do. I have a list of videos, these videos are inside of competitions and are given votes if someone likes the video. Each video will have a vote number and a competition number. I am trying to rank based on votes within competition. So for example below I have competition 8, I need the rank of all the videos in that competition based on votes. I then need the same for competition 5 etc.

```
  |rank|votes|competition|
  ------------------
  |  1 | 100 | 8   |
  ------------------
  |  2 |  50 | 8   |
  ------------------
  |  3 |  30 | 5   |
  ------------------
  |  1 | 900 | 5   |
  ------------------
  |  2 |  35 | 5   |
  ------------------
```

I have tried various group and selectby methods but nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Comment: So you don't have a rank column in your table i guess ? and you need the rank from query right

Comment: Correct, Even if I did have a rank column I would still need a query to calculate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mysql you can use user-defined variables to calculate rank,case statement checks if competition is same as the previous row then increment rank by one if different then assign 1 an order by is needed to have correct rank for the video

```
 SELECT t.*,
   @current_rank:= CASE WHEN @current_rank = competition 
             THEN  @video_rank:=@video_rank +1 
             ELSE @video_rank:=1 END  video_rank,
   @current_rank:=competition
FROM t ,
(SELECT @video_rank:=0,@current_rank:=0) r   
  ORDER BY competition desc, votes desc
```

### [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a6f5/3)

If you are confused with the last extra column you can use a subselect

### [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a6f5/4)

Comment: Ah! it worked perfectly! You my friend are a wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windowing functions:

```
select
    competition, votes, rank() over (partition by competition order by votes desc) as rank
from
    table1
```