# Update mysql rank by column value grouped by column value

Tags: mysql, rank

Starting from these examples.

1 [mysql rank by column value grouped by column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023824/mysql-rank-by-column-value-grouped-by-column-value)

2 [Multiple Ranks in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/)

They explain how to calculate the rank grouped by the value of a column. In my case **ship**

I need a **update** of "rank" column, 
instead of a **select**

```
| iduser | ship  | score | rank  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|   25   |   1   |   7   |   0   |
|   25   |   3   |  21   |   0   |
|   25   |   4   |  30   |   0   |
|   12   |   9   |  23   |   0   |
|   25   |   9   |  18   |   0   |
|   21   |   9   |   5   |   0   |
```

Must be updated:

```
| iduser | ship  | score | rank  |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|   25   |   1   |   7   |   1   |
|   25   |   3   |  21   |   1   |
|   25   |   4   |  30   |   1   |
|   12   |   9   |  23   |   1   |
|   25   |   9   |  18   |   2   |
|   21   |   9   |   5   |   3   |
```

This is the select query

```
SELECT  iduser,
        ship,
        score,
        ( 
            CASE ship 
            WHEN @curShip 
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curShip := ship END
        ) AS rank
FROM    ship_stats,
        (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curShip := '') r
ORDER BY ship DESC, score DESC;
```

Comment: So you're looking for an update statement? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm

Comment: yes. I need an update :)

Comment: Why should one of use write your code for you. At least have a try for yourself. If you get problems come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you attempted to write.

Comment: I thought that was clear from the title.
I made the select. But I have not been able to do the update.
The example is in the schema I made.
and in select query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried for myself. This is a specific question: I found several similar example on stackoverflow. But not "update". So I thought it could be useful also for others. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @curship = 0,@curRow = 0;
UPDATE ship_stats 
SET rank := 
        (CASE ship 
            WHEN @curShip 
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curShip := ship END
        )
ORDER BY ship DESC, score DESC;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/883c9d/1)